# Have dependencies be included in the final jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have two java projects:

- MainProject
- LibraryProject

I use Maven to build my `MainProject`. In pom.xml of `MainProject`, I defined the dependency of `LibraryProject`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.xxx.LibraryProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>LibraryProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Under `MainProject` root path, after I run : `maven clean install` a **MainProject.jar** is generated. But those classes defined in `LibraryProject` & invoked by `MainProject` are not available in this **MainProject.jar**.

How can I have the `LibraryProject` classes available in the **MainProject.jar** ?

I have tried [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) , but it doesn't work for me. I need the dependency be included in the **MainProject.jar**

Comment: "I have tried Maven Assembly Plugin , but it doesn't work for me" ... why not? That's exactly what it does.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer, I have read the link you provided, but after did that & execute command "mvn clean compile assembly:single" , I didn't see the generated MainProject.jar, but if I do "mvn clean install" it is generated, the LibraryProject's classes are still not available

Comment: @Mellon  then you didn't set up the `<executions>` section

Comment: @Brian Roach, could you please provide a sample ?

Comment: @mellon The sample in the A to linked Q should work perfectly fine. I use it to provide a .jar including all the dependencies for the Riak Java client, [pom.xml is here](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/blob/1.4.4/pom.xml#L376) (it's in its own profile, but that doesn't change the config)